# How to keep your dev-stack separated from your project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, devstack

I'm thinking about way to keep my JS dev-stack separated (updatable) from my project.

The situation is this: I've just created my very first dev-stack based on Webpack and I want to start building a first project based on this dev-stack. But what if sometime in the future I will decide that I want to change some core functionality of the dev-stack (e.g. some changes with my Webpack plugins). Now I need to make this changes both in the dev-stack and in all project based on this dev-stack.

What is the best-practice of dealing with situation like this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like a module system: define a package in one place and use it in multiple projects. Given that you're working in JS, you can treat each part that you want to isolate as a node module. Typically that would mean publishing the module to NPM, but you could alternatively put each on github and reference the github location in the package.json of each of your projects. This pattern of defining a project's dependencies which are pulled from a centralized repo is pretty common, even when the dependencies are your also your projects.

If you want to work on both the dependencies and the projects that use them in parallel on your local machine, one decent solution is `npm link`. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link This lets you replace a dependency in a node project with a symlink to a local copy of that dependency. npm will use your local version of the module instead of trying to pull it from its remote location, so you can easily test and make changes to the dependency without having to publish it or manually copy-and-paste between the two projects.

Comment: I understand maybe half of what you wrote but thank you!